# get Error 6A82 (file not found) on select file by reading an NFC ISO 14443-4 Card with isoDep in Android

Tags: android, nfc

I am reading NFC Cards in my APP.
All Cards are nearly the same.
But on some Cards I can not select the file. I know that everything is right with my ADPU, because a friend of mine has a similar APP and he can select the file with the same APDU.
The data on the Cards are Bus tickets. So I checked this cards with 5 different apps. 3 couldnt read this cards 2 could read this cards. I sent the APDU with "NFC Tools" and got Error 6A82.
Is there some other way to select the file with AID? Is there a special parameter in setting up IsoDep?

I tried everything and find no solution.
Here is a part of my code.:

```
        if (intent != null) {
        val tag: Tag? = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        if (tag != null) {
            try {
                IsoDep.get(tag).use {
                    it.run {
                        connect()
                        timeout = 20000
                        val selectAppDir =
                            transceive("00A4040C0CD2760001354B414E4D30310000".hexStringToByteArray())
```

I set the timeout to 20 seconds, because somebody had problems with the timeout. But the timeout is no solution, I tried a lot of different timeouts.

Any hints?

BR Helmut